# Recalculating raster values in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I need to multiply two raster's  using "Raster Calculator'. However, in one of the rasters I want to use the Values in a new field that I have calculated. But, when I use the Raster Calculator tool, it multiplies the original filed (Value) of Raster1 into Raster2 and I don't have any option to use the field that I am interested.

So, I think I need to change the Values in the Raster1 first somehow?

Not sure how to do this. See below the table of Raster1, where I want to multiply Acreage value into another raster's values.

Acreage was computed as Value/Count

[image: Attribute Table]

Comment: Try lookup in spatial analyst

Answer (score 1):

Your Acreage field is simply an attribute you created and tagged onto the end of the raster attribute table. It is Value field in the raster dataset that holds the value of the pixel. To *replace* the pixel value to the value held in the Acreage field you need to do the following:

1. Export the attribute table of your Raster1 dataset to a stand alone table, e.g. c:\temp\remap.dbf
2. Run your raster through the [Reclass by Table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/reclass-by-table.htm) tool to replace the pixel values.

Comment: thanks for the comment, it seems that the approach suggested by FelixIP above, would do what I am after

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "[Lookup](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/lookup.htm)" tool in Spatial Analyst would do what I am after.
[Lookup tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/lookup.htm)